# RegistryKey.CreateSubKey not working on Azure hosted environment

Tags: c#, azure, tfs, registry

I'm using `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` to do queries on cloud TFS. At some point it tries to create a registry key using `RegistryKey.CreateSubKey` method, but it fails with:

`System.IO.IOException`: *The specified registry key does not exist*.

Works fine on a local machine, but fails when deployed into Azure (as a web site).

I tried givng specific rights to writing to the registry using something like `[RegistryPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, ViewAndModify = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0")]`but with no effect.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Is your website running under shared mode? I don't think you can manipulate registry keys through an application running in a Windows Azure Websites. Reason being multi-tenancy - there are many applications like yours running under one VM/Physical Box.

Comment: Same if I changed it to Standard mode...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like    `TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>()` does funny things, and not sure why it wants to use the registry (I think it has to do with the integrated functionality in Visual Studio that connects to TFS).

I ended up using the `WorkItemStore` constructor and passing the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` instance to it.

Majority of the on-line examples recommend using the `tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>` without acknowledging the implications.

Hope this hint can help others in this situation.

Comment: So does that mean now you are not using Registry entries right? Because I dont think even with Standard instances of AzureWebsites, you can do those registry manipulations. Even for Standard instances, there is no RDP support for AzureWebsites, that shows how much they are protected as an environment. For registry level operations, I would suggest Webroles or VMRoles.

Comment: Taking a look at the code in the WorkItemStore constructor that doesn't know about the TeamProjectCollection, it indeed does try to open registry keys for HKCU.